# 5 asteriscos en archivo CRONTAB. Que significa?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crontab

mi consulta es sobre que significan el siguiente comando en mi sistema linux, se que es un bash de CONTRAB pero no logro entender porque usa cinco asteriscos:

```
* * * * * curl http://mi-ws/obtenerMensaje
```

Comment: Es la sintaxis de crontab a través de la cual le indicas con qué periodicidad ejecutar el comando. Mira [el manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html), o si prefieres [la entrada de wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_(Unix))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las tareas [cron](https://geekytheory.com/programar-tareas-en-linux-usando-crontab) siguen una determinada sintaxis.

```
* * * * *  /ejecutar_comando

De izquierda a derecha, los asteriscos representan:

1. Minutos: de 0 a 59
2. Horas: de 0 a 23
3. Día del mes: de 1 a 31
4. Mes: de 1 a 12
5. Día de la semana: de 0 a 6, siendo 0 el domingo
```

En el ejemplo `* * * * *` significa:

```
1. Cada minuto
2. Cada hora
3. Cada día del mes
4. Cada mes
5. Cada día de la semana
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
30 2 * * 1 /ejecutar_comando

1. En el minuto 30
2. De las 2 de la noche
3. De cada día del mes
4. De cada mes
5. Sólo si es viernes
```

Comment: Ahora entiendo amigo, gracias. Tengo una última duda. No se supone que también va el usuario que ejecuta la tarea, como por ejemplo root. O es que acaso a veces se puede omitir?

Comment: Eso es depende de usuario de sistema y configuración... te daré 2 enlaces con más información: [1](https://voragine.net/linux/crontab-usuarios-sistema-tareas-periodi) | [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419548/how-to-set-up-a-root-cron-job-properly)

Answer (score 0):

`man 5 crontab` establece que el valor del asterisco (*) se toma como los valores desde el primer hasta el último valor aceptado de cada campo "primero-último". Un "*" en el campo de los minutos, sería equivalente a "0-59", lo análogo para los demás campos.

Los valores aceptados por campo son:

```
field          allowed values
-----          --------------
minute         0-59
hour           0-23
day of month   1-31
month          1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

Donde, en día de la semana, 1 es lunes, 5 es viernes, 0 y 7 son domingo.

Lo pongo de esta manera porque habrán notaciones de la forma:

```
*/2 */6 * * * etc
```

Que serán equivalentes a

```
0-59/2 0-23/6 1-31 1-12 0-6 etc
```

Respecto a tu pregunta sobre al usuario que ejecuta la tarea. Cada usuario tiene su propio crontab. Si haces un `sudo crontab -e`, editaras el archivo crontab del usuario root, al mismo tiempo que si haces `crontab -e` desde un usuario, editaras el archivo crontab de ese usuario.